# Read HTML Table value in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So, I have an HTML table which is rendered dynamically by calling an external URL. The table looks like this after rendering:

```
<table class="cart-totals calc-totals-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="calc-total-row">
            <th>Total:</th>
            <td class="text-right">$41.93</td>    <-- Get this value
        </tr>
        <tr class="calc-unit-price-row">
            <th>Unit Cost:</th>
            <td class="text-right">$0.17</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I cannot make any changes to the table. I want to get the value on "Add to Cart" button click.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents(<current_page_url>);

$dom = new domDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        echo $cols;
}

?>
```

But after adding the above code, the page keeps on reloading.

Comment: Do you get any errors if you remove the @ sign from the @$dom->loadHTML line?

Comment: `code` $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

Replacing the 1 with a 0 could do it.

Comment: why don't you use JavaScript if you want to get the value on  "Add to Cart" button click?

Comment: if you need to get the cart total there are the woocommerce APIs to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think you're reloading due to a fatal error.

Using your example I modified the code to work. Changes are commented.

```
$dom = new domDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

// Change 1
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {    
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

    // Change 2
    echo $cols->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

Change 1
The sample you provided has only 1 table, thus it must be referenced at index 0.

Change 2
`echo $cols;` is an error because $cols will be a DomNodeList object.
 (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

`->item(0)` returns the first item in the list which will be a DOMNode object.
 (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php).

To get the text value of a DOMNode you use the `textContent` property.

EDIT: 
You can also use xpath to navigate the dom tree for you.

```
$dom = new domDocument();    
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$query = new DOMXpath( $dom );
$result = $query->evaluate( "string(//table[contains(@class, 'cart-totals')]/tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'calc-total-row')]/td)" );
if($result){
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: It still takes too much time to load the page but is also giving a Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: invalid element name in Entity and an Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on null

Comment: in loadHTML() I'm passing the complete url of the page with protocol

Comment: "Invalid element name" suggests the html is badly formatted and DOMDocument cannot parse it. Elements like <001> might trigger this as node names cannot start with numbers.  First verify you're actually downloading the html then look for invalid elements.   You may need to strip those out or find a different solution.  See here for rules. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to get the value on "Add to Cart" button click, I suggest you to use JavaScript instead of PHP.

**Try below Snippet:**

```js
$('#add-to-cart').click(function(e) {
  var total = $('tr.calc-total-row td').html();
  alert(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="cart-totals calc-totals-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="calc-total-row">
      <th>Total:</th>
      <td class="text-right">$41.93</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calc-unit-price-row">
      <th>Unit Cost:</th>
      <td class="text-right">$0.17</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add-to-cart">
Add to Cart
</button>
```

Comment: add to cart is a woocommerce button but not a simple HTML. I want to call this inside a wc-hook